# Php code on XAMPP working from Wifi, but not from my phone under 4g

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, xampp, 4g

I've done an android application to login on my database and register accounts on my XAMPP server.
This application works fine from my PC and from my phone, but only when i'm under WiFi connection.
When i switch to Mobile connection (4g in my case) doesn't work on my smartphone.

System catches an IOException and writes in a dialog that i've configured just the url of the php file, like "http://EXAMPLEIP/login.php".

Somebody knows if is it a configuration problem?
Don't mind EXAMPLEIP, on my code there is the correct ip taken from ipconfig command.

I handle the connection with an AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {

    code = voids[0];
    username = voids[1];
    password = voids[2];

    if(code==LOGIN_CODE){
        web_address = "EXAMPLEIP/login.php";
    }else if(code==REGISTER_CODE){
        web_address = "EXAMPLEIP/register.php";
        bestPlace = voids[3];
    }

    try{
        URL url = new URL(web_address);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
        if(code==LOGIN_CODE){
            data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")
                    +"&&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
        }else if(code==REGISTER_CODE){
            data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")
                    +"&&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")
                    +"&&"+URLEncoder.encode("bestPlace","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(bestPlace,"UTF-8");
        }
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1"));
        String line ="";
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            result += line;
        }
        reader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return result;

    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        result = e.getMessage();
    }catch (IOException e){
        result = e.getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tell your example ip's. One will not be correct.

Comment: "http ://ip-taken-from-ipconfig/login.php"

Comment: You should tell two ip's. Real values. Dont continu not telling them.

Comment: It's not safe but i'm really Sure that are corrects because i use them in php config file too when i call a new mysqli and works

Comment: Of course you can tell a local ip like 192.168.2.12 as the whole world has the same local ips. But what is more interesting is the other ip that you use.

Comment: It's the same, changes Just that at the end instead of login.php there is register.php

Comment: http ://192.168.1.21/login.php without the space

Comment: That is the local ip of your pc and can be used by your Android client if connected with wifi to the same network. If your Android client uses a mobile connection instead then the phone could as well be in New York, Berlin or your home and that local ip of your pc can not be used.